# React onChange won't fire when bootstrapswitcher is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use a bootstrapswitch to React. I'm initializing the component and passing the props. But when I change the state of the button by clicking it, on change function doesn't fire. The button seems to be working fine but something is overriding the onChange function of the input field.

How can I prioritize my onChange function? Or is there a better solution?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ReactBootstrapSwitch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isChecked: false
        }
        this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            checkBoxText: this.props.checkBoxText,
            isChecked: this.props.isChecked
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.$(`[name=${this.props.id}]`).bootstrapSwitch();
    }

    onChangeHandler(event) {
        alert('Hi')
        this.setState(function (previousState, props) {
            if (previousState.checked === true) {
                alert('A')
            } else {
                alert('B')
            }
            return {
                isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
            }
        }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-check form-check-switch form-check-switch-left" >
                <label className="form-check-label" >
                    <input onChange={event => this.onChangeHandler(event)}
                        name={this.props.id}
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="form-check-input form-check-input-switch"
                        data-off-color="warning"
                        data-on-text="On"
                        data-off-text="Off"
                        checked={this.state.isChecked}>
                    </input>
                    <b>{this.state.checkBoxText}</b>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ReactBootstrapSwitch
```

Comment: Are you getting alerts?

Comment: Nope that is the problem. It's not running my **onChangeHandler** function

Comment: Is `bootstrapSwitch` is working? Are you getting switch?

Comment: Yes the switch is working properly but I can't handle it's event with React

Comment: Something wrong with `bootstrapSwitch`, just comment the `componentDidMount` and check your onchange handler is working properly. You must check the docs for `bootstrapSwitch`.

Comment: You mean docs right ?

Comment: Why don't you try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-switch . Using this you don't have to worry about jquery and initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have already `bind`ed the function. Use that one instead of creating another.

```
<input onChange={event => this.onChangeHandler(event)}
```

Should be:

```
<input onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
```

given `onChange` is the right prop to handle event changes.

Comment: I think that doesn't matter.

Comment: @ravibagul91 it matters coz it's not memoized.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isChecked: false
        }
        this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            checkBoxText: this.props.checkBoxText,
            isChecked: this.props.isChecked
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // window.$(`[name=${this.props.id}]`).bootstrapSwitch();
    }

    onChangeHandler = (event) => {
        alert('Hi')
                    if (this.state.checked === true) {
                alert('A')
            } else {
                alert('B')
            }
        this.setState({
                isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
            });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-check form-check-switch form-check-switch-left" >
                <label className="form-check-label" >
                    <input onChange={event => this.onChangeHandler(event)}
                        name={this.props.id}
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="form-check-input form-check-input-switch"
                        data-off-color="warning"
                        data-on-text="On"
                        data-off-text="Off"
                        checked={this.state.isChecked}>
                    </input>
                    <b>{this.state.checkBoxText}</b>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App1
```

See this

Comment: Code without explaination?

Comment: Are you using it with bootstrapswitcher ?

Comment: No I dont have that package installed

Comment: Well the problem seems to be the bootstrapswitcher. I think it has a onChange method and it overrides the input's onChange method. @RahulRana your solution works but don't do what I want